# Python -- How do you view output that doesn't fit the screen?

Tags: python

I should say I'm looking for a solution to the problem of **viewing output that does not fit on your screen.** For example, range(100) will show the last 30ish lines in your terminal of 30 height.

I am only looking to be nudged in the right direction and am curious how you guys have approached this problem.

What have you done when you run into a situation where you wish you could conveniently scroll through some large output?

### Best Answer

Use the scrollback buffer on your terminal.

If you're using GNU Screen, it can be set with `defscrollback 1000` or any other number in `HOME/.screenrc`.

Use `Ctrl-a, [` to enter copy mode

```
j -    Move the cursor down by one line
k -    Move the cursor up by one line
C-u -  Scrolls a half page up.
C-b -  Scrolls a full page up.
C-d -  Scrolls a half page down.
C-f -  Scrolls the full page down.
G -    Moves to the specified line
```

The best part is `?` for reverse search, `/` for forward search while in copy mode.

Super convenient.

Thank you!

---

### Original question:

What is the python equivalent of the bash less command?

```
LongString | less
```

Is there something like that for python? I find myself thinking I could use it fairly often but just move on and find some other solution.

By "long things" I mean anything that generates more output lines than my screen. 1000 print messages, a dictionary, a large string, range(1000), etc.

My googlefu has failed.

Comment: To view very long things formatted as what and in what context? To read through long strings in a paginated way?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "for Python". In what situation does `less` not work for you?

Comment: I'm looking at myobject.log which is a very long string.

I'd like to be able to scroll through it in the python interpreter. How can I do that?

Comment: @Yuji: Can you open another window?  Can you use `less` in the other window?  What's stoping you from doing that?  Are you aware that Python's `help` function uses `less`?

Comment: Hi S, I don't understand what you mean by other window / using less there. I'm curious how to use less in the first place in python on random output: say range(100). 

Should I look into os.system()? No I was not aware that help uses less. Should I look into how help works?

Comment: @Yuji - are you talking about doing this for output while working in the interpreter, or for output resulting from running a script at the bash (or whatever) command line?

Comment: Are you aware of the [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) module, by the way? Usually `pprint.pprint` or `pprint.pformat` helps to print greatly nested structures.

Comment: @detly I'm referring to the interpreter. I'm often in there and I come across some data attached to an object I'm messing around with that's too long, but I'd still like a quick glance at it.

Comment: My Bash screen allows me to literally zoom out with two finger touch on the touchpad just like I can on Chrome. This lets me see larger outputs sometimes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this for an interactive python session, you should use a terminal emulation that allows you to scroll back up. I believe most of them do.

If you're using an actual terminal, or if you don't have a choice of terminal emulators, perhaps you can use [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

(If you're using Windows, you can change the screen buffer size to allow scrolling back up to 9999 lines).

And if you need this for the output of your program, you can try to use the [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) module to implement scrolling yourself.

Comment: This is sounding like a great solution! Facepalm! I just need to raise my scrollback buffer way up in screen. 

Ooohhh will try this tomorrow. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: Raised my GNU Screen scrollback buffer to 10k : ) 

Can navigate up half page, full page, etc conveniently. 

Thanks for the answer itsadok! I will write about it in the hopes that others find it useful. It seems hard to ask this question without getting attacked for better coding practice, don't get in the situation in the first place, etc. You were supremely helpful.

Answer (score 10):

just for fun :o)

Original version for Python2:

```
class Less(object):
    def __init__(self, num_lines):
        self.num_lines = num_lines
    def __ror__(self, other):
        s = str(other).split("\n")
        for i in range(0, len(s), self.num_lines):
            print "\n".join(s[i: i + self.num_lines])
            raw_input("Press <Enter> for more")

less = Less(num_lines=30)  
"\n".join(map(str, range(100))) | less
```

a Python3 version:

```
class Less(object):
    def __init__(self, num_lines):
        self.num_lines = num_lines
    def __ror__(self, other):
        s = str(other).split("\n")
        for i in range(0, len(s), self.num_lines):
            print(*s[i: i + self.num_lines], sep="\n")
            input("Press <Enter> for more")

less = Less(num_lines=30)  
"\n".join(map(str, range(100))) | less
```

Comment: Surely you meant `class More` :)

Comment: Really great answer, it's a small and elegant code snippet that can be placed in any script. It's also cross-platform (tested on Windows 7) and doesn't require any external library.

Comment: This is quite nice, but one drawback here is that it is synchronous; your program is stopped while waiting for the user to finish scrolling through the output.

Comment: @NateGlenn This seems more useful for the python interactive console than for actual scripts, and the console is synchronous anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way and it is quite trivial, that's why not specifically described. Say you have long list and want to see just the beginning:

```
>>> lst = range(1000)   # let's make list of thousand elements
>>> lst[:100]           # i want to see just the first 100
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
>>> lst[100:201]        # ok, now the 2nd hundred 
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200]
>>> lst[-100:]          # and now just the last 100, pretty please?
[900, 901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 912, 913, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928, 929, 930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 940, 941, 942, 943, 944, 945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 953, 954, 955, 956, 957, 958, 959, 960, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969, 970, 971, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988, 989, 990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999]
```

The same `[]` slicing works the same for strings. For dictionary you can cheat somehow, like   using `str()` to convert it to string and then display with the same slicing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Say you're writing a program in Python and all it does is pretty print some stuff. The output is in `prettiest_print_ever`. You already do weird tricks importing `fcntl`, `termios`, `struct` and friends to get the terminal size so that you can use the full width of the terminal (if any); that also gives you the screen height, so it makes sense to use it. (That also means you've long given up any pretenses of cross-platform compatibility, too.)

Sure, you can reinvent the wheel, or you can rely on less like other programs do (e.g. `git diff`). This should be the outline of a solution:

```
def smart_print(prettiest_print_ever, terminal_height = 80):
  if len(prettiest_print_ever.splitlines()) <= terminal_height:
    #Python 3: make sure you write bytes!
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(prettiest_print_ever.encode("utf-8"))
  else
    less = subprocess.Popen("less", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    less.stdin.write(prettiest_print_ever.encode("utf-8"))
    less.stdin.close()
    less.wait()
```

Comment: The last bit there with subprocess and less was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/stable/html/overview.html) you can issue shell commands within your interactive python session. That means that you just do

```
In [1]: less myfile.txt
```

I also really like being able to arrow up and down to get previous commands and getting the output from previous commands by doing something like

```
In [33]: print cos(Out[7]*pi/180)
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I love ipython and being able to use commands. I do use that frequently and love being able to edit files from within. My output would be in the interpreter, so no filenames. I suppose I could save the output as a file :P can I pipe in output to less directly?

Comment: I haven't used the edit command in ipython much, and I'm not sure how you name your files. I tend to edit Python files with Eclipse or gedit, and use ipython when I want to inspect how some of my code is working interactively.

Answer (score 0):

There's one fundamental difference between less run in a shell, and Python: Python is a programming language, less is a program.

Bash is aware of what the linecount is in the console, and less can query that (and a number of other things), Python on its own can't be, it's a language and it's agnostic to its environment (that's left to libraries).

On top of that, less obeys some of its own standards. Careted lines get moved to top, it feeds to termcap, it's conceptually part of the OS tools, and it's meant to send to output even if it hasn't finished reading the file.

You can write less in Python if you want, or run it from inside a python script, but its functionality is more (and too specific) than a single method of file should contain.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer. I should rephrase and say I'm looking for a solution to my problem of viewing output that's larger than my screen. So far, it seems I need to write my own that splits various output into chunks, but it seemed like something that would exist.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is json serilizable then you can try

```
import simplejson
print simplejson.dumps({'shipping-line': {'price': '0.00', 'code': 'Local Pickup (Portland, OR)', 'title': 'Local Pickup (Portland, OR)'}}, indent=4)
```

Output will be look something like

```
{
    "shipping-line": {
        "price": "0.00", 
        "code": "Local Pickup (Portland, OR)", 
        "title": "Local Pickup (Portland, OR)"
    }
}
```

this is specifically used to debug and to see the actual content......in well readble format..

**EDIT:**

if your screen is limited to 25 lines..........

```
import simplejson
data = simplejson.dumps({'shipping-line': {'price': '0.00', 'code': 'Local Pickup (Portland, OR)', 'title': 'Local Pickup (Portland, OR)'}}, indent=4)

cnt = 0

for line in data.split('\n'):
    cnt+=1
    print line
    raw_input() if cnt%25==0 else None
```

Comment: Hey shah, thanks! but what if the output is 10x longer and won't fit my terminal? The output scrolls to the bottom. Is my solution only to slice it?

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to write your own:

```
def less(s, line_count = 5):
    lines = []
    for i, line in enumerate(s.split('\n'), 1):
        lines.append(line)
        if (i % line_count) == 0:
            yield '\n'.join(lines)
            lines = []

    if lines:
        yield '\n'.join(lines)
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks! I thought about a way or two to split various output but it seems like something so common that it would be built in. I was surprised I couldn't google it.

Answer (score -2):

> What have you done when you run into a situation where you wish you could conveniently > scroll through some large output?

1. Don't create large output.  Use functions to summarize or show selected details.
2. Simplify the application to avoid creating large output in the first place.
3. Focus what I'm looking at to avoid large output.
4. Generally avoid large output.

It seems simpler to avoid large output than to fuss around trying to display something I never cared about in the first place.

Comment: Hi S, thanks for that, but I'm specifically talking about those small situations where i DO run into large output. 

Normally, I know exactly what should be in a dictionary so large output isn't a problem. But if once every full moon, I'll be in a situation where I'm in python, and I pull up a database entry that has a large entry that I'd rather not go to PGSQL for.

I wish you guys would help with the real issue, not suggest my issue is invalid.

Comment: @Yuji: Sorry but you're missing the point.  Your issue **is** invalid.  You have Python.  You can write code.  So write code.  Please write code to manipulate/summarize/filter/extract your data.  Please just write code -- that's why you're using Python.

Comment: I'm sorry you don't seem to get my point: I asked what to do when you run into large output. You answered to not have large output in the first place. I completely agree, I stay away from it, but when you do run into a situation where some code you don't control spits out 100 print statements and want to see the first line, what do you do?

It is not simpler to avoid large output as that would require time and effort modifying a foreign program when all I'm interested in is a glance at the output. 

I hope I'm making sense here. Not running into these situations is certainly ideal  :)

Comment: The solution is to raise the scrollback buffer in whatever terminal you're using and scroll up :P yay. zero coding, super convenient, and exactly the kind of answer I'm looking for. 

The answer to "what do you do when you wish you could scroll through some large output" is "scroll through the large output" :D Thank you all

Comment: "some code you don't control"  Doesn't make sense.  Stop using it.  Subclass it, or write your own version.  You can see the source.  You can fix the source.  You don't have to endure other people's bad design.  This is Python -- you can fix it.

Comment: I honestly have no idea why you're being so argumentative. I don't need to take a gun to a knife fight, I was looking for a solution that is as easy and convenient as possible: found it. Thanks!

Comment: @Yuji: You keep arguing with my answer.  I gave you an answer -- to which you keep posting arguments.  You don't have to agree with my answer.  You already picked another answer as the one you agree with.  I cannot understand your problem.  I'm arguing that your problem does not make sense to me.  I have never had it.  I cannot see how anyone could have it.  You can continue arguing if you want; but you already accepted another answer.

Comment: Sorry to put that on you S. You're right, it's me arguing. I was assuming  my point could be understood. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @Yuji: Your point is understood.  And you're looking in the wrong places.  Looking for help from outside the core Python language misses the value of Python.  You have a language that allows you to write good code.  Use it.  Filter, Summarize, Focus.  Fix the bad software that dumps too much stuff.  **Use The Language**.

Comment: I use the django ORM testing ideas in the interpreter, so I often have something like myblogpost.body. The large output in this case is not a mistake on my part or improper python (right?) I'm not saying it's right to read blog posts in the interpreter, but I find myself in these situations where I already have someobject in the interpreter, and pulling up someobject.thingtoread is faster than going to SQL or the web to get the same information. Is it still wrong to have a solution outside the language? I think the interpreter is hard to separate from the terminal, so it's not so far outside.

Comment: @Yuji: "Is it still wrong to have a solution outside the language?".  Yes.

Comment: @Yuji: I use the Django ORM every day (8 hours a day!)  I have never had a problem viewing output.  I have Python.  I use Python.  QueryResult objects are list-like and and I can use list programming techniques **in the interpreter**.  Directly.  Really.  Every day.  I can "slice" and "sort" and use "for" statements and everything.  In the interpreter.  Interactively.

Comment: For me, the less i know about the data, the faster scrolling is (3 keystrokes +1 per page). The more I know about it, the faster sorting/slicing is. 
Both have their place.
As for the right/wrong of looking outside the language? We are essentially of different religions, and we can only walk away or kill each other. I'll take the former.

Comment: "We are essentially of different religions, and we can only walk away or kill each other"  Makes very little sense.  Are you still arguing about my answer?  Why?

Comment: The religion comment was a joke about how it's important to you to stay in python, while it's not to me. I'm trying to exit!

Comment: @Yuji: I can't understand any of these comments.  What point are you making?  Can you summarize?  Are you simple repeating that you don't like my answer?  If so, why continue to repeat that you don't like my answer?  What have I missed.  You don't like my answer.  I get it.  What else is there?  You couldn't find your scroll buffer settings.  I get it.  What else is there?

Comment: @Yuji: communicate what?  What are you trying to communicate?  Are you still trying to explain your preferred answer?  Why?  Why does it matter that I agree with anything?  I don't think your problem in sensible.  You can continue to explain it, but I can only see it as non-sensical.  Why continue to pound away at this thread?  What is your point?  What point are you trying to make?