# Displaying Real Time Text in Shell with Python

Tags: python

I have a large amount of text (around 200 lines). That I want to display in real time within the Linux shell.

i.e In realtime I mean I print the letters 1 2 3 4 to the screen and then after 1 second print 2 3 4 5. This is achieved in essence by the following code.

```
    sp.call('clear',shell=True)
    print("\033[%d;%dH%s" % (x,y,output))
```

The issue I have is that when I print a large amount of text to the screen and then reprint over the top of it. I only see the bottom part of the text.

Im looking for any python methods, classes etc that may allow me display large amounts of text whilst displaying in realtime and also allow the user to easily scroll through the output (i.e maybe scrolling, sidebar' etc.).

Comment: Does the part of your question after the code have anything to do with what you wrote before that?

Comment: Have you tried anything? 200 lines isn't really that large, so I'm not sure that is relevant to the question.

Comment: question updated. its not the easiest thing to describe : )

Answer (score 0):

The [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) module allows you to position the cursor in a terminal and then write the relevant text.

It's up to you to create a buffer in memory for the whole file and keep track of the position in the buffer that is represented by the top-left of the visible window. Any time the visible window position changes (eg when the user scrolls) you can then redraw the appropriate text for the current window.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Python -- How do you view output that doesn't fit the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305287/python-how-do-you-view-output-that-doesnt-fit-the-screen) and see if there's any interesting solution there.

Simple one would be piping your python process to less, e.g. `python myprogram.py | less`
If you want more control use the curses module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html